# Fill the dates in the middle knowing the starting and ending dates

Tags: vba, excel

I guess this could be done in other languages, but I have to use VBA, which I am newbie.

There are two lists that select dates (all are the end of months) in sheet1. Once they are selected, they are the starting and ending dates. The starting date will be copied to A1 of sheet 2. I hope there is a way to dynamically fill the rows of column A until the ending dates. Any way, either through VBA or Excel formula to do it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand Start Date to End Date with Series of EOMONTHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256792/expand-start-date-to-end-date-with-series-of-eomonths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA with startdate in Sheet1!B1 and enddate in Sheet1!B2 as,

```
With Worksheets("sheet2").Columns("A")
    .Cells.Clear
    .Cells(1) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, "B").Value2
    .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlDay, _
                Step:=IIf(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, "B").Value2 > Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, "B").Value2, 1, -1), _
                Stop:=Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, "B").Value2
    Intersect(.Cells, .Cells.Parent.UsedRange).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this without VBA, using a helper column.  In your new spreadsheet where you have a full list of dates, put this formula next to it.  For ease of use, I've named a cell `startDate` and `endDate` which we can use.

```
=IF(AND(A5>=startDate,A5<=endDate),A5,"")
```

Where column A are *all* the dates, the formula is in column B.  The dates appear/disappear as timeframe is adjusted.

[image]

Edit: As @ScottHoltzman astutely pointed out, you can actually skip using a helper column.  In A5, `=startDate` then in `A6` put this and fill down: `= IF(A5+1<=endDate,A5+1,"")`

Comment: *dynamically fill the rows of column A until the ending dates* - why not write formulas directly into column A. `A5 = startDate`. Then `A6 = IF(A5+1 <=endDate,A5+1,"")`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - ...because I didn't think of that!  Good idea! (Add as an answer, or I can edit in to my post)